# Android Studio: autoSize of EditText doesn't work

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-edittext

in my current project there's an EditText with fixed layout_width and layout_height, called `exercise` that is expanded downwards programmatically: `One line of text (String) + "\n"` is added to the EditText.

Sometimes the line added to the EditText, let's call it element, is too long to fit inside the full width of the object so it's splitted into a new line.
The thing is I would either like the lines' text size in `exercise` to be resized to fit the EditText's width or have a clear visible distance between each line (element), but just not inside the newline due to not fitting inside the `exercise`'s width.

Therefore I googled as much as I could and tried out every possible solution I could find today.
What I tried:

- Using either **`EditText`** as the object and `android:autoSizeTextType="uniform"` & `android:inputType="textMultiLine|textCapSentences"`as attributes or **`androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatEditText`**, accompanied by the attributes `app:autoSizeMaxTextSize="28sp"`, `app:autoSizeMinTextSize="8sp"`and `app:autoSizeStepGranularity="1sp"`
  (with a device that supports just exactly API 26)
- using other types of text objects
- using `lineSpacingExtra` to insert some spacing. This unfortunately also inserted the spacing between the wrapped/ splitted line so the original element's line that got splitted by wrapping inside the EditText had the spacing aswell.

That's where I am now. I can't get the text size be reduced automatically when the line would be too wide for the EditText's width.

I could supply the full XML, if needed.

I'm grateful for any hint that could help here. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Auto-sizing text affects the size of *all* the text in the `TextView`, it should work fine for a single line (also if you use ``app:autoSizeTextType`` instead of `android:` it'll work down to API 14). You could try messing around with `Spannable`s to change the size of different lines of text in the same `TextView`, but are you sure you don't just want a list view of some kind? That way each entry is completely independent, has its own `TextView` that can be sized appropriately, can be easily edited without having to go to the correct line etc

Comment: Thanks first of all for your advice!
I also tried the `app:autoSizeTextType` object for compability reasons with no effect.
Not sure if `Spannable` will be helpful enough/ won't get too messy but I will have a look at it.

Of course I thought about just going with a `List View` but I remembered working myself for days through half an hour tutorial videos of difficult to understand people on YouTube which sometimes left me with more errors than I began with. Plus I would like to save the `exercise`'s contents for later re-use so I found it easier to save and re-import a string than a list.

Comment: I've put a basic implementation in an answer for ya, just so you can see how it could work. I know a lot of people watch video tutorials now, but honestly a well-written tutorial article is a lot easier for me to work with - plus you can skim it and get an idea if it's decent or not. And storing a list of `String`s isn't much harder than a `String` on its own, and you're keeping separate things separate in your logic. Whatever works for you, but if you're taking data and smooshing it into one big string for convenience, you'll probably hit a point where it's not very convenient anymore!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a really basic `RecyclerView` implementation (using view binding, let me know if you're not familiar with that - you can just `findViewById` all the things instead):

[image: A picture of the result, with multiple lines at different sizes]

```
class MainFragment : Fragment(R.layout.fragment_main) {

    lateinit var binding: FragmentMainBinding

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        binding = FragmentMainBinding.bind(view)
        with(binding) {
            val adapter = MyAdapter()
            recyclerView.adapter = adapter
            recyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(requireContext())

            addButton.setOnClickListener {
                val item = textEntry.text.toString()
                if (item.isNotBlank()) {
                    adapter.addItem(item)
                    textEntry.text.clear()
                }
            }
        }
    }


}

class MyAdapter : RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.ViewHolder>() {

    private var data: List<String> = emptyList()

    fun addItem(item: String) {
        data = data + item
        notifyItemInserted(data.lastIndex)
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
        val view = ItemViewBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context), parent, false)
        return ViewHolder(view)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.binding.textView.text = data[position]
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int = data.size

    class ViewHolder(val binding: ItemViewBinding) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root)
}
```

```
fragment_main.xml


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:padding="10dp">

<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/textEntry"
    />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/textEntry"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:singleLine="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/addButton"
        />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/addButton"
        android:text="ADD"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        />


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

```
item_view.xml


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingHorizontal="16dp"
    >
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        app:autoSizeTextType="uniform"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="48sp"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        />

</FrameLayout>
```

It's pretty simple - you have a text entry field and a button to add the contents as a new line. The button passes the contents to `addItem` on the adapter, which appends it to the list of lines in `data`. The `RecyclerView` just displays all the items in `data`, using a `ViewHolder` layout that has an auto-sizing `TextView` to scale each item.

Ideally you'd want to persist `data` somehow (e.g. the Add button passes the new data to a `ViewModel`, stores it somehow, updates the current list which the adapter has `observe`d so it updates whenever there's a change) - I just left it as a basic proof of concept. Also, it's easier to store separate items if they're kept separate - you can always serialise it by joining them into a single string if you really want! But generally you wouldn't want to do that

---

**edit** - since you're having trouble with the `setTypeface` thing, this is all it is:

```
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
    with(holder.binding.textView) {
        val styled = position % 2 == 0
        text = data[position]
        setTypeface(typeface, if (styled) Typeface.BOLD else Typeface.NORMAL)
        setTextColor(if (styled) Color.RED else Color.BLACK)
    }
}
```

[image: An example of the RecyclerView with alternate items styled differently]

The logic is just styling alternate items differently, but hopefully you get the idea. You decide how to style a given item depending on what it is, and then you apply that style by setting attributes as appropriate. It's always an "if **this** is true do *A*, **otherwise** do *B*" situation, so you're always setting the attribute one way or the other. You never only set it for one case, because then you're leaving old state displayed if it's *not* that case.

---

It's more complicated, but you also have the option of creating *different* `ViewHolder`s (with their own XML layouts) for different kinds of item. So instead of having a single `ViewHolder` that has to work with everything, where you have to reconfigure things like all the styling in `onBindViewHolder` depending on which type of item is displayed, you can just have different `ViewHolder`s with different styling, different layouts etc:

```
// creating a sealed class so we can say our adapter handles a MyViewHolder type,
// and we can have a specific set of possible subclasses of that
sealed class MyViewHolder(view: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view)
class HeaderViewHolder(val binding: HeaderItemBinding) : MyViewHolder(binding.root)
class ItemViewHolder(val binding: ItemViewBinding) : MyViewHolder(binding.root)

// the Adapter now uses the MyViewHolder type (which as above, covers a couple of different
// ViewHolder classes we're using)
class MyAdapter : RecyclerView.Adapter<MyViewHolder>() {

    private var data: List<String> = emptyList()

    fun addItem(item: String) {
        data = data + item
        notifyItemInserted(data.lastIndex)
    }

    // some identifiers for the different ViewHolder types we're using
    private val HEADER_TYPE = 0
    private val ITEM_TYPE = 1

    override fun getItemViewType(position: Int): Int {
        // Work out what kind of ViewHolder the item in this position should display in.
        // This gets passed to onCreateViewHolder, where you create the appropriate type,
        // and that type of ViewHolder is what gets passed into onBindViewHolder for this position
        return if (data[position].startsWith("Section")) HEADER_TYPE else ITEM_TYPE
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): MyViewHolder {
        val inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
        // creating the appropriate ViewHolder instance depending on the type requested
        return when(viewType) {
            HEADER_TYPE -> HeaderViewHolder(HeaderItemBinding.inflate(inflater, parent, false))
            ITEM_TYPE -> ItemViewHolder(ItemViewBinding.inflate(inflater, parent, false))
            else -> throw RuntimeException("Unhanded view type!")
        }
    }
    
    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MyViewHolder, position: Int) {
        // The type of MyViewHolder passed in here depends on what getItemViewType returns
        // for this position - binding is a different type in each case,
        // because it's been generated from different layouts
        when(holder) {
            is HeaderViewHolder -> holder.binding.textView.text = data[position]
            is ItemViewHolder -> holder.binding.textView.text = data[position]
        }
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int = data.size

}
```

(You could be a bit more clever than this, but just to illustrate the general idea!)

That's using the same `item_view.xml` as before, and a `header_item.xml` variation on that (but you could have literally anything, they're completely separate layouts, completely separate `ViewHolder`s):

```
header_item.xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingHorizontal="16dp"
    >
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        app:autoSizeTextType="uniform"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="48sp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="#DD1100"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

[image: An example of using different ViewHolders with their own independent layouts]

So instead of having to "redesign" one `ViewHolder` in code to go back and forth between different item types and their styling, You can just use two differently-styled layouts. It's a bit more work to set up, but it can be neater and much more flexible when you have completely independent things - especially if you want to give them different functionality. It depends whether it's worth it to you, or if you're happy to just have a single `ViewHolder` and restyle things in code, hide or show elements etc.

Comment: Thank you very much for your efforts! I agree with you, it's far easier to follow a well written article about such an implementation than watch somebody on youtube write some code and explain in broken english.
I have to solve an error with button colors first, then I will give it another shot with the recycler view, adapters and stuff from your answer. I will keep you updated on the implementation process. Thanks for the motivation to be more professional here :)

Comment: Omg yes, it works! At first I was not able to see the EditText and the button as they were obstructed by the navigation bar. Once I set the FragmentContainerView's `layout_height`  to 0dp it adapted to the available height and showed the EditText and button :)
The button (identically to your XML) is completely white though (no text visible) but that's no problem as I wanted to have the list items added from a hashmap anyway.

Thank you so much for your advice!

Comment: @MalteGe no worries, glad you got it working! It's a little more complicated than just having one big `TextView` but I think it'll be easier to manage, and probably nicer for the user too. btw if your button's showing up white that might be a theming issue, that up there is just the base Material theme. If your buttons are all white (and their text is still the default white too) it'll look like nothing's there on a white background

Comment: Thanks man! I just implemented your code a second time in my program at a different location and have learnt a lot about the Recycler View, adapters and so on.
One question I couldn't yet overcome: If I'm using your design & functions with the new data being updated in the ViewHolder - how could I possibly pass something like textStyle=bold to the TextView inside the item_view.xml?
I tried duplicating the Adapter just for these header text lines with bold text that referred to a duplicated item_view.xml.

Comment: Unfortunately calling this adapter for the header with `recyclerView.adapter = adapterHeader
            recyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(requireContext())` and then using the same but with the normal `adapter` didn't actually change the style of the header lines.

What's the elegant solution for this? Thanks again!

Comment: If you want to make one of the items in the list bold, you do it in `onBindViewHolder`. That's where you *bind* a particular piece of data to the `ViewHolder` that displays it - so basically you set stuff so it looks right for that piece of data. `textView.setTypeface(textView.getTypeface(), Typeface.BOLD)` will make it bold (`NORMAL` for normal), and there are some more complex setters in `TextView` you can look at, for CSS-style styling. If you want to style parts of text, use spans when setting the text https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/spantastic-text-styling-with-spans-17b0c16b4568

Comment: Alright, that works, thanks!
What I wanted to do though, to go even a step further, is to have the `textView`'s typeface altered individually. With `textView.setTypeface(textView.typeface, Typeface.BOLD)` every line of `textView` is set to bold.
I thought I might do it as a second step by referring to a part of the the textView already there like by `textView.text[0]` but `setTypeface` doesn't work on Strings but the textView itself.
Do you know a way to deal with this to have the textView altered individually? Could I do it with a newly created function in MyAdapter?

Comment: @MalteGe in `onBindViewHolder` you have to set up *the entire `ViewHolder`* to reflect the current item's state. So if the current item should be bold, you need to set `Typeface.BOLD` on it - **otherwise** you need to set it to `Typeface.NORMAL` because there's a possibility it's already been set to bold for the last item it displayed. You're reusing these `ViewHolder`s so you have to set up their whole state each time for all the bits that could change. If you mean you want to style *part of the text* in a single `TextView`, not the whole thing, you need to use a `Spannable` like in that link

Comment: I guess I understood what you mean. Before I recalled that the `RecyclerView` implements a TextView for every list item I tried using `Spannables` as you advised.
Started with `if (data[position].startsWith("Sprünge in den")){
                spannable = SpannableStringBuilder(data[position])
                spannable.setSpan(StyleSpan(BOLD),0,lastline.length, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE)
                spannable.setSpan(ForegroundColorSpan(Color.RED),0,lastline.length,Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE)
            }` but failed transferring the last `data`line to `spannable`.,

Comment: Then I realized a typeface change for the whole `textView` is fine as I could alter this for every list object that gets added to the `RecyclerView` if I've understood you correctly.

The thing is, I still don't know how to appropriately set the `typeface` to `BOLD`or `NORMAL` for the `ViewHolder`. I failed trying to call this typeface alternation in an upper function that actually creates the text for the `textView` by e.g. somewhat like `adapter.onBindViewHolder()...`

Could you enlarge on that a bit more? 
I'd happily buy you a coffee for your efforts, if you like btw :)

Comment: @MalteGe nah don't worry about it, but thanks! You just set the typeface in `onBindViewHolder`, same as how you set the text it's displaying in there. That function gets called by the adapter when it needs to display the item at `position` in the list, so you're just configuring the reusable `ViewHolder` instance it's giving you. It's the same as setting any other attribute - setting a background colour, deciding if a box should be checked, displaying a particular image etc. However the data should be represented, that's where you do it. I'll throw an example in my answer

Comment: Thank you so much man! Really appreciating your efforts to explain this new solution, makes sense to me now. The solution with modulo is a neat one for a quick typeface switch. I wish I could use this for the header usecase but suppose I'll be needing a second viewholder. And here you provided the exact thing I was missing - how to differentiate between two viewholders - I didn't know about sealed classes but they indeed do the trick. I will implement this when I'm having a bit more time later the week, trying to work with the one viewholder and your first solution until then. Thanks again :)

Answer (score 0):

you can try something like this

```
if(et.getText().length()>10) {
        et.setTextSize(newValue)
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice! Do you know if it is possible to have this affect just a single line rather than the whole `EditText`?

Comment: you just add this to your edit text `android:lines="1"`

Comment: upvote if it was helpful to reach other users!

Comment: I already tested the impact of `android:lines="1"`on my app (sorry I didn't say earlier) and when there's too much text for one line so it would be escaped in a second line, this line simply gets cut out.
So this is no solution either :(